# Firebase IP Restrictions

Tags: firebase, ip-restrictions

We're about to develop a chat engine using Firebase that will be used in schools. This means that it will appear to Firebase that there are potentially up to 60 simultaneous connections from one IP address. I imagine that this might look like an attack or dodgy traffic.

Does anyone know if that is likely to cause a problem? Is Firebase likely to block such IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if that is likely to cause a problem?

It won't cause any problem.

> Is Firebase likely to block such IP addresses?

Why would they wanna block it?

Is it because:

> This means that it will appear to Firebase that there are potentially up to 60 simultaneous connections from on IP address

What did you expect? If 60 people from different machines with different IP address make requests to Firebases, I expect Firebase to see them as separate connections, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Check the firebase pricing for more details on how much [simultaneous connections are possible](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) with the 'Spark Free' subscription you're on now, and when you might need to upgrade.

Comment: Thx Rexford for replying. The issue is that because of school proxy servers it sometimes looks like it is a single IP address connecting multiple times. They do not have different IP addresses.